# Is there a SQL/English like language that lets you define formulations given some data?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, applications, modeling

It would be very useful for beginning and non technical users to be able to define models in a way that was natural for them. Further this could perhaps assist generating some kind of generic modelling language which could be used in applications.

Inspired by the [BDD (Behavior Driven Development) library](http://lettuce.it/tutorial/simple.html)

For example, let's take a diet like problem. It could be stated as:

```
Given I have ingredient banana
Given that a banana costs 1 unit
The ingredient banana has 10 units of potassium
Find me the cheapest ingredient combination for 100 units of potassium
```

Maybe it's an implementation detail? And I should just define the types of constraints and parse the string data? Is this an area of research?

Comment: People not thinking in SQL after date of birth? 0 rows returned?

Comment: I wonder if [Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/) could be used to solve this. Not sure if prolog could perform that last sentence requirement.

Comment: I think there's a bit of an uncanny valley type effect going on here. If you tell users that "hey, this thing understands English," but it doesn't have a full understanding of all possible English, then your users are bound to get frustrated by the short-comings, in a way that they wouldn't with a  "machine language" (i.e. systematic, optimized for easy and non-ambiguous parsing), where users "prepare themselves" and set some expectations.

Comment: Great, now graduates will have another excuse not to learn programming!

Answer (score 11):

Not answering your question, but related: I just came across a paper ([Wang, Shi, and Reddy 2019](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.01839.pdf)) that aims to translate natural English into SQL queries. Here's an example of their results:

[image]

Maybe this can be a useful starting point if you're searching for literature on this, or starting to build your own English-to-modelling-language translator.

Comment: greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something similar was featured on the [Stackoverflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/31/the-next-generation-sql-explore-a-new-way-to-analyze-visualize-and-share-data/) some weeks ago.

Comment: This paper also has a similar idea - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.05774.pdf

Answer (score 11):

MiniZinc is the closest I know of. In terms of syntax, it is closer to
Python, R, and MATLAB than SQL. However, it is a pretty powerful language.

**[Example](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.1/en/modelling.html#ex-cakes2):**

```
% Baking cakes for the school fete (with data file)

int: flour;  %no. grams of flour available
int: banana; %no. of bananas available
int: sugar;  %no. grams of sugar available
int: butter; %no. grams of butter available
int: cocoa;  %no. grams of cocoa available

constraint assert(flour >= 0,"Invalid datafile: " ++
                  "Amount of flour should be non-negative");
constraint assert(banana >= 0,"Invalid datafile: " ++
                  "Amount of banana should be non-negative");
constraint assert(sugar >= 0,"Invalid datafile: " ++
                  "Amount of sugar should be non-negative");
constraint assert(butter >= 0,"Invalid datafile: " ++
                  "Amount of butter should be non-negative");
constraint assert(cocoa >= 0,"Invalid datafile: " ++
                  "Amount of cocoa should be non-negative");

var 0..100: b; % no. of banana cakes
var 0..100: c; % no. of chocolate cakes

% flour
constraint 250*b + 200*c <= flour;
% bananas
constraint 2*b  <= banana;
% sugar
constraint 75*b + 150*c <= sugar;
% butter
constraint 100*b + 150*c <= butter;
% cocoa
constraint 75*c <= cocoa;

% maximize our profit
solve maximize 400*b + 450*c;

output ["no. of banana cakes = \(b)\n",
        "no. of chocolate cakes = \(c)\n"];
```

Answer (score 5):

It is a little uncommon these days, but prolog is well suited to this type of problem.  It allows you to concisely state and efficiently solve a wide variety of interesting things.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316504/zebra-puzzle-who-lives-on-which-floor as well as a whole mess of tagged questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+zebra-puzzle as examples.

Answer (score 3):

### Controlled natural language

There's a bunch of research in using controlled natural language (e.g. in the CNL workshop https://link.springer.com/conference/cnl) and one of the use cases is for making queries in some knowledge base. If the data and its ontology is in a structured format such as RDF, then there exist tools for querying that data directly (usually with SPARQL), there are a bunch of tools for visualizing the models/ontologies and the data in them, and there are also natural language querying tools such as http://aksw.org/Projects/AutoSPARQL.html or https://github.com/AKSW/NSpM which I admittedly haven't tried. It's a whole field of research that's not that related to operations research, but there are some interesting things there.